# why doesnt .destroy() work for labels in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a login system. When you enter an incorrect password or username, it will show "username or password incorrect" and then when you change it into a correct one, it's supposed to destroy the previous one and display the new one, but instead, it doesn't destroy the previous message, so you can see it under the new one [username or password incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCPEX.png) [it overlaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROYvJ.png)

here's the code:

```
def submit_li(usern, passw, screen):
    global users
    global login_un
    global login_suc
    login_un = tk.Label()
    login_suc= tk.Label()
    login_un.destroy()
    login_suc.destroy()
    password = str(passw)
    username = str(usern)
    global login
    login = False

    for user in users:
        if username == user[0] and password == user[1]:
            login = True

    if login:
        login_suc = tk.Label(screen, font=('Arial', 13), text=f"{username} has logged in!")
        login_suc.grid(column=0, row=3)
        login = False
    else:
        login_un = tk.Label(screen, font=('Arial', 13), text="Username or password incorrect")
        login_un.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

i tried destroying it i was expecting it to delete the previos label and display the new one and the output was it displaying over the previos label

Comment: Why don't you create the label once outside the function? Then you can simply update the text of the label inside the function based on the login status.

Comment: @Andrew. It is not a practical using looping.

Answer (score 2):

You created two labels with empty string and then destroy them at the beginning of `submit_li()`.  Then you create another label for the login status.  Therefore the later label will never be destroyed.

You can simply create the label for login status once outside the function and update it inside the function:

```py
def submit_li(usern, passw, screen):
    global login

    password = str(passw)
    username = str(usern)

    for user in users:
        if username == user[0] and password == user[1]:
            login = True
            msg = f"{username} has logged in!"
            break
    else:
        login = False
        msg = "Username or password incorrect"

    # update the login status label
    login_status.config(text=msg)

...

# create the label for login status
login_status = tk.Label(screen, font=('Arial', 13))
login_status.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

...
```

Comment: it still overlapps the previous label https://ibb.co/R2mzSXN https://ibb.co/Nxc3fXv

Comment: @Andrew I think you didn't implement my code correctly because I don't have such issue.  Your code still create label inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the main problem is the tkinter didn't destroy the labels correctly, and the cause of the problem is your these two lines:

```
login_un = tk.Label()
login_suc= tk.Label()
```

The only thing you need to adjust is to change these two lines into this:

```
try:
    login_un.destroy()
    login_suc.destroy()
except:
    pass
```

I also test acw1668's code but doesn't work for me. But his explanation and analysis are completely correct. That is why your code dosen't work.

> You created two labels with empty string and then destroy them at the beginning of submit_li(). Then you create another label for the login status. Therefore the later label will never be destroyed.

I think this one will help you.